# SSH tunnle to mongodb using mongodb connection string

Tags: linux, mongodb, ssh, openssh

Thought it should be straight forward but I have a very hard time figuring out the following:

I got mongodb connection string: `mongodb://user:password@123.123.123.111:27017/?authSource=admin`

I want to be able to connect to mongo from localhost at port 1234 by doing: `mongo localhost:1234`
The solution is to create a tunnel, but nothing I do works for me.

I tried the following command:

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:27017 user:password@123.123.123.111 -p 27017
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Mongo uses connection pools.  When you attempt to establish a connection via the default port 27017 the pool will redirect to a different unused port.  This allows multiple concurrent connections.  This is probably causing you grief in your efforts to tunnel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a unix user on 123.123.123.111

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:27017 UNIXuser@123.123.123.111
```

Then your local mongodb connection string is : mongodb://user:password@localhost:1234/?authSource=admin

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB and ssh use different protocols, so you can't use ssh to connect directly to a mongod process.

If you want to use an ssh tunnel you will first need to have an account on the destination machine, and use that account's credentials with ssh to connect to port 22 (assuming default port).  The mongod username/password will probably not be valid for ssh.

Once the tunnel is established, you would connect to the local port using a driver or mongo shell using the connection string:

```
mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:1234/?authSource=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH tunneling to access your MongoDB.

Linux/mac

`ssh root@171.51.336.21 -L 27018:127.0.0.1:27017 -N`

Connection String:

`mongodb://localhost:27018/betterdatabase?authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority&directConnection=true`