# How to connect mongodb with url

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb.
I have db url, and I want to connect to that server from my ubuntu terminal and access data on terminal.
can anyone please help me how to connect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH tunnle to mongodb using mongodb connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558391/ssh-tunnle-to-mongodb-using-mongodb-connection-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have the [URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) and the mongo shell installed, you can connect using the following command:

`mongo <uri>`

For example, if you want to log in as `admin` with the password `mypassword` through `example.com` on the port `27017`, you can do:

`mongo mongodb://admin:mypassword@example.com:27017/?authSource=admin`

See:
[how can I connect to a remote mongo server from Mac OS terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813912/how-can-i-connect-to-a-remote-mongo-server-from-mac-os-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

If mongodb version is 5.x.x
`mongosh --host ip`